# Generalization of binary operators?

Tags: group-theory, relations

While exploring combinations of posets, I've come across a ternary relation $R$ on a 5-set (of posets) that looks a little like the operation for some group, though it's clearly not $C_5$... not least because $R$ isn't even univalent. I gather that some authors would describe $R$ as a [multivalued function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function).

Here's what $R$ looks like, displayed as though it were a group operator:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
    & e & a & b & c                 & d \\\hline
  e & e & a & b & c                 & d \\
  a & a & e & c & \mbox{$b$ or $d$} & c \\
  b & b & c & e & \mbox{$a$ or $d$} & c \\
  c & c & \mbox{$b$ or $d$} & \mbox{$a$ or $d$} & \mbox{$e$ or $c$} & \mbox{$a$ or $b$} \\
  d & d & c & c & \mbox{$a$ or $b$} & e \\
\end{array}
$$

So I have two questions:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
  1. & \mbox{Are these operation-ish beasts a thing?} \\
  2. & \mbox{And for this particular $R$, does anybody recognize it from somewhere else?}
\end{array}
$$

**UPDATE**

I now have the answer to question 1. Beasts like $R$ have indeed been studied, and they are known in general as [hyperstructures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperstructure).

Comment: *I've come across a ternary relation* $R$ *on a* $5$-*set* --- Book, paper, lecture notes, blog post, ...? Knowing which might help others. In my case, I wonder if perhaps this was an exercise in which one is to choose specific values for each of the multi-valued entries to obtain an operation having a certain specified property.

Comment: I'm a little surprised by the $(c,d)$ vs. $(d,c)$ entries - everything else is symmetric, but there we have "$a,b$, or $c$" vs. "$a$ or $b$." Is that correct?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I'm working a research problem in order theory, not asking for help with a homework problem. I hope that my edits to the question provide enough of the kind of context that you suggest may be useful.

Comment: The google searches ["multigroup" + "multivalued"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22multigroup%22+%22multivalued%22) *AND* ["group" + "multivalued operation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22group%22+%22multivalued+operation%22) *AND* ["multivalued binary operation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22multivalued+binary+operation%22) might turn up something.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, thanks for your question. It turns out I had done a poor job of fact-checking my table. I don't know why the asymmetry in the version I'd originally posted didn't catch my eye. In any event, I've fixed that mistake and I **think** the table is now correct.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveL.Renfro for the suggested searches. I've updated the OP with an answer to the more general of my two questions.

Comment: When the operation is associative, they are also sometimes known as multisemigroups (at least this is the term I saw them called by when they show up in the theory of $2$-categories).